# Turning off point markers does not appear to work for Highcharts-ng

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, angularjs-directive, highcharts-ng

I am trying to turn off the markers on a line chart using [highcharts-ng](https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng).

I've checked the highcharts API and I believe I need to pass in the option:

```
plotOptions: {
    line: {
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }
}
```

However, I tried this in highcharts-ng and it does not appear to be working and I am pretty stumped. Here is a slightly modified stock example where I pass in this option to no effect: 
http://jsfiddle.net/BnnVN/

Answer (score 0):

Rather workaround than solution: http://jsfiddle.net/BnnVN/2/

Instead of using plotOptions, disable markers for specific series.

```
    series: [{
        data: [10, 15, 12, 8, 7, 1, 1, 19, 15, 10],
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }],
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to nest the `plotOptions` inside the `options` object.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Cp73s/4348/